# Difference between 尽くす and きれる

Tags: word-choice, subsidiary-verbs

I know both 尽くす and きれる mean to do something fully/completely
eg(these are my own examples)

> 色々やり尽くす。(I have tried all the methods or I have exhausted all the methods.)

generally I have heard of

> 食べきれない。(cannot complete the food...)

What I want to know is when do we use 尽くす and きれる.

How do I know if I can say やり尽くす or やりきれる?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an explanation by feeling rather than logic, but **V+きる** strikes me as if pushing a progress bar until the end, while **V+つくす** marking off all items in a list one by one. People use ～きる when you achieved 100% of an assumed entirety of work needed to call it completed, and ～つくす, when you leave none of ever imaginable targets.

That's why ～きる is typically associated with a goal, or "the point you don't have to continue" (especially in potential form ～きれる), and ～つくす against available resource, or "the point you have no means to continue". In another aspect, ～きる usually focuses on a single item or event, where ～つくす has multiple items in mind.

They sometimes have a complex interaction with the verb's meaning (besides many non-transparent idioms e.g. 乗り切る, 張り切る etc.) that I can't really make a sweeping summary, but hope you grasp a feel from examples below:

> やりきる (do a single thing to the end)
> やりつくす (do every possible thing; try every possible way)
>
> 食べきる (eat until 0% left / to do) ≈ 食べつくす (eat until nothing remains)
>
> ○ 疲れきる (so tired that HP down to 0)
> × 疲れつくす (it's difficult to assume some kind of "fatigue" list)
>
> 一本の木を使いきる (use a piece of lumber completely)
> 一本の木を使いつくす (make full use (every possible application) of a piece of lumber)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation."pushing a progress bar until the end" -> this really helped me understand.